# I wanna achieve "Send Email" functionality via a visualforce page on a custom object page layout

Tags: apex, quote

I have a custom Quote object,and I wanna achieve the same functionality as of a standard Quote object,How could I achieve Send Quote functionality via a VF page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom button for send mail functionality with on Click JavaScript.

```
location.replace('/email/author/emailauthor.jsp?retURL=/{!Quote.Id }&p2_lkid={!Quote.Contact.Id }&template_id=00X11000000IHt5&p3_lkid={!Quote.Id}&p3={!Quote.name }&p26=''&p4=''&p5=');
```

See the explanation below:-

> p3_lkid = "Related To" Id. Based on the Id, Salesforce will
>   automatically select the object and record. This Id will be used to
>   populate the merge field, if you are also using a template.
>
> retURL = Return URL if cancel is pressed. Followed by %2F.
>
> p2_lkid = Contact Id. Use to populate "To" field. It automatically
>   fetches the email of this contact to send email. Also, populates the
>   contact merge fields, if used.
>
> p4 = CC
>
> p5 = BCC. I passed two emails separated by semicolons to keep two
>   different people in the loop. Same goes with CC field.
>
> p6 = Subject of this email.
>
> p23 = Email body.
>
> p24 = Additional emails.
>
> template_id = Id of template you are going to use. This template
>   should contain merge fields of the same object as p3_lkid. No need to
>   pass p6 and p23, if the template already handles them.

To add more parameters, please see the structure above.